# Why does my association model find subgroups in a dataset when there shouldn't any?

Tags: python, machine-learning, language-agnostic, scikit-learn, data-mining

> I give a lot of information on the methods that I used to write my code. If you just want to read my question, skip to the quotes at the end.

I'm working on a project that has a goal of detecting sub populations in a group of patients. I thought this sounded like the perfect opportunity to use association rule mining as I'm currently taking a class on the subject.

I there are 42 variables in total. Of those, 20 are continuous and had to be discretized. For each variable, I used the [Freedman-Diaconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule) rule to determine how many categories to divide a group into.

```
def Freedman_Diaconis(column_values):

    #sort the list first
    column_values[1].sort()

    first_quartile = int(len(column_values[1]) * .25)
    third_quartile = int(len(column_values[1]) * .75)

    fq_value = column_values[1][first_quartile]
    tq_value = column_values[1][third_quartile]
    iqr = tq_value - fq_value
    n_to_pow = len(column_values[1])**(-1/3)
    h = 2 * iqr * n_to_pow
    retval = (column_values[1][-1] - column_values[1][1])/h
    test = int(retval+1)
    return test
```

From there I used min-max normalization

```
def min_max_transform(column_of_data, num_bins):
min_max_normalizer = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(1, num_bins))
data_min_max = min_max_normalizer.fit_transform(column_of_data[1])
data_min_max_ints = take_int(data_min_max)
return data_min_max_ints
```

to transform my data and then I simply took the interger portion to get the final categorization.

```
def take_int(list_of_float):
ints = []

for flt in list_of_float:
    asint = int(flt)
    ints.append(asint)

return ints
```

I then also wrote a function that I used to combine this value with the variable name.

```
def string_transform(prefix, column, index):

transformed_list = []
transformed = ""
if index < 4:
    for entry in column[1]:
        transformed = prefix+str(entry)
        transformed_list.append(transformed)
else:
    prefix_num = prefix.split('x')
    for entry in column[1]:
        transformed = str(prefix_num[1])+'x'+str(entry)
        transformed_list.append(transformed)

return transformed_list
```

This was done to differentiate variables that have the same value, but appear in different columns. For example, having a value of 1 for variable x14 means something different from getting a value of 1 in variable x20. The string transform function would create 14x1 and 20x1 for the previously mentioned examples.

After this, I wrote everything to a file in basket format

```
def create_basket(list_of_lists, headers):

#for filename in os.listdir("."):
#    if filename.e

if not os.path.exists('baskets'):
    os.makedirs('baskets')

down_length = len(list_of_lists[0])

with open('baskets/dataset.basket', 'w') as basketfile:
    basket_writer = csv.DictWriter(basketfile, fieldnames=headers)

    for i in range(0, down_length):

        basket_writer.writerow({"trt": list_of_lists[0][i], "y": list_of_lists[1][i], "x1": list_of_lists[2][i],
                                "x2": list_of_lists[3][i], "x3": list_of_lists[4][i], "x4": list_of_lists[5][i],
                                "x5": list_of_lists[6][i], "x6": list_of_lists[7][i], "x7": list_of_lists[8][i],
                                "x8": list_of_lists[9][i], "x9": list_of_lists[10][i], "x10": list_of_lists[11][i],
                                "x11": list_of_lists[12][i], "x12":list_of_lists[13][i], "x13": list_of_lists[14][i],
                                "x14": list_of_lists[15][i], "x15": list_of_lists[16][i], "x16": list_of_lists[17][i],
                                "x17": list_of_lists[18][i], "x18": list_of_lists[19][i], "x19": list_of_lists[20][i],
                                "x20": list_of_lists[21][i], "x21": list_of_lists[22][i], "x22": list_of_lists[23][i],
                                "x23": list_of_lists[24][i], "x24": list_of_lists[25][i], "x25": list_of_lists[26][i],
                                "x26": list_of_lists[27][i], "x27": list_of_lists[28][i], "x28": list_of_lists[29][i],
                                "x29": list_of_lists[30][i], "x30": list_of_lists[31][i], "x31": list_of_lists[32][i],
                                "x32": list_of_lists[33][i], "x33": list_of_lists[34][i], "x34": list_of_lists[35][i],
                                "x35": list_of_lists[36][i], "x36": list_of_lists[37][i], "x37": list_of_lists[38][i],
                                "x38": list_of_lists[39][i], "x39": list_of_lists[40][i], "x40": list_of_lists[41][i]})
```

and I used the apriori package in [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) to see if there were any association rules.

```
rules = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(patient_basket, support=0.3, confidence=0.3)
print "%4s %4s  %s" % ("Supp", "Conf", "Rule")
for r in rules:

    my_rule = str(r)
    split_rule = my_rule.split("->")

    if 'trt' in split_rule[1]:
        print 'treatment rule'
        print "%4.1f %4.1f  %s" % (r.support, r.confidence, r)
```

Using this, technique I found quite a few association rules with my testing data.

> THIS IS WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM

When I read the notes for the training data, there is this note

> ...That is, the only
>   reason for the differences among observed responses to the same treatment across patients is
>   random noise. Hence, there is NO meaningful subgroup for this dataset...

My question is,

> *why do I get multiple association rules that would imply that there are subgroups, when according to the notes I shouldn't see anything?*

I'm getting lift numbers that are above 2 as opposed to the 1 that you should expect if everything was random like the notes state.

```
Supp Conf  Rule
 0.3  0.7  6x0 -> trt1
```

Even though my code runs, I'm not getting results anywhere close to what should be expected. This leads me to believe that I messed something up, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I realized that my sample size is too small for the number of variables that I have. I would need a way larger sample size in order to really use the method that I was using. In fact, the method that I tried to use was developed with the assumption that it would be run on databases with hundreds of thousands or millions of rows.